# using for loop to instantiate a map

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a for loop to add key-value to a map:

```
std::map< std::pair<const int &, const int &>, double> mymap;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
mymap[std::make_pair(i,i+1)]=0.1*i;
}
std::cout<<mymap.size()<<std::endl;
```

I don't understand why the size of `mymap` is just 1. I expect 3 to be the size. Where did I make a mistake? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `std::pair<int, int>` instead of `std::pair<const int&, const int&>`.

`const int&` is a *reference* (as opposed to value). Since `i` has the same location each time, and it's possible for the same temporary location to be used for the `i+1`, that means you could be using the same pair each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<pair<const int,const int>, double> mymap;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        mymap[make_pair(i,i+1)]=0.1*i;
}
cout<<mymap.size()<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Will give output as 3 That '&' you have used made all the difference. i think it is taking of some sought of reference.